# SignalR not serializing enum values on custom type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, enums, signalr

I have a self-hosted SignalR server passing data to a .NET SignalR client. Essentially, it is doing a continuous or on-demand update of a custom type. When I want to trigger an update, I create a data transfer object, load it with the data to send, and send it via SignalR. The client side captures the update and displays the new values (I have a WPF app and a Console app and both do essentially the same thing - the WPF app just does it a little "prettier"). Everything works fine for most of the properties on my DTO. But there are two properties that are enum values and those always come across to the client as the enum's 0-value (in my case "Unknown") no matter what I set it to on the server side. On the server side, I trace it all the way to the

```
Clients.All.updateData(data);
```

call and the DTO (data) has the correct enum values all the way to that point. But putting a breakpoint on the client side right at the point of the function that receives calls from the server, the DTO has incorrect (0) values for both enums. I have searched online for any possible issues with SignalR serializing enum values and I have not come across anything. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Dennis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after much stumbling around it appears that I needed to add setters to the public enum properties on my DTO to get them to serialize (or, more accurately I believe, to get them to deserialize) correctly. Originally I had immutable properties (which worked fine for my other properties of primitive types). I tried many things - from changing the property names (which originally were the same as the name of the enum type), to updating my Newtonsoft package in my client, to adding the Json converter stuff. But it appears that what finally did the trick was adding setters to my enum properties. I still don't know why that is or if there's another way around my issue (if anyone has any ideas, let me know!), but that fixed it. Thanks to those who replied.

Dennis

Answer (score 26):

ASP.NET Core 3.x or higher

```cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

services.AddSignalR()
    .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
    {
        options.PayloadSerializerOptions.Converters
           .Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    });
```

ASP.NET Core 2.2 or lower

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

services.AddSignalR()
    .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
    {
        options.PayloadSerializerSettings.Converters
            .Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    });
```

Additional Reading: [ASP.NET Core SignalR configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration)

Comment: Starting from .Net Core 3.x it should be updated to `PayloadSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter())`

Comment: Hi @Ramūnas - like that?  Please see the updated answer.  IMHO we, users of stackoverflow, should edit answers so we don't have to read through comments to get things working.

Comment: what about the using statement?  probably only applies to before Core 3 

Comment: Indeed, now it is `using System.Text.Json.Serialization`

Answer (score 7):

You said you checked everything online, but I still hope this [link](http://serena-yeoh.blogspot.ch/2014/04/serializing-enums-in-aspnet-signalr.html) could be useful.

Just adjust your Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Create JsonSerializer with StringEnumConverter.
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    // Register the serializer.
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () => serializer);

    app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```